# Do I need to include foreign VAT while declaring goods for personal use at UK customs?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, import-taxes, tax-refunds, vat

Suppose I buy personal goods worth 4500 AED (1000 GBP approx) in UAE and arrive at the UK. I am a UK resident.

Now suppose that I have paid an additional 225 AED (50 GBP approx) as VAT in UAE. So the total amount paid noted in the printed invoice is 4500 AED + 225 AED = 4725 AED. Now there are two possible things that can happen.

Case 1: Suppose I apply for VAT refund before leaving UAE, so I will be expecting a VAT refund of 190 AED (42 GBP approx).

Case 2: Suppose I do not apply for VAT refund, so I will not be expecting any VAT refund.

Now here are my questions:

1. In case 1, while making my customs declaration at https://www.tax.service.gov.uk/check-tax-on-goods-you-bring-into-the-uk/where-goods-bought, should I declare 4535 GBP (product price + total foreign vat - refunded foreign vat) as the “price paid” amount for the goods? Or should I declare 4725 AED (product price + total foreign vat)? Or should it be just 4500 AED (product price only)?
2. In case 2, should I declare 4725 AED (product price + total foreign vat) as the “price paid”? Or should it be just 4500 AED (product price only)?

Comment: Too lazy to look up a reference at this time hence comment not answer, but I’m pretty sure it should be the cost without VAT in any case.